# 2 way binding with Vue3 Inline template (using slots) in laravel blade template files

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade, vuejs3

**In Vue3, inline-templates were depreciated and now slots are used. Is it possible to have 2-way binding of variables for Vuejs components written in blade templates?**

I want to have 2-way binding for Vue components that's written inline with blade templates. Although I know I can pass data like `<example-component name="Hello World">` [It is a ton of work to add props everywhere](https://medium.com/@konafets/localization-with-laravel-and-vuejs-e27068e68ee8).

[Vue recommends using slots as a inline-template replacement since it got removed in v3](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/inline-template-attribute.html#option-2-default-slot), however, that documentation makes no sense. I've got the components displayed using the code below. It's a dead simple text field + paragraph to display the name.

home.blade.php (Removed unnecessary HTML for brevity)

```
<div>
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>

    <example-component>
        <div class="container">
            <input v-model="name" placeholder="Change Name"/>
            <p> Name is @{{ name }} </p>
        </div>
    </example-component>
</div>
```

example-component.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                name: 'hi',
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Unfortunately, this does not work, the name doesn't start as 'hi' and doesn't update when changing the textfield. When I try something like `<slot :name=name></slot>`. Which I believe would pass the name into the slots section, the component gets rendered for a second before disappearing.

Is having 2-way binding with vue variables in blade templates even possible? Any help is appreciated.

- Vue: 3.0.5
- Laravel: 8.29.0

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you're storing the data in the child component? The reactivity design works by passing props down and emitting events up, even though (unfortunately) the reactivity is not maintained when passing a variable up to the parent component. Seems a little counter intuitive, but I might be missing something in what you're trying to create.

It will, however, work if you put the data into the app instead of the component.

```js
// app 
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      name: 'hi',
    }
  }
})

// component
app.component('example-component', {
template: `
    <div>
        <slot></slot>
    </div>`,
})

app.mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.5/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>

    <example-component>
        <div class="container">
            <input v-model="name" placeholder="Change Name"/>
            <p> Name is @{{ name }} </p>
        </div>
    </example-component>
</div>
<!--
```

Comment: Interesting, the core reason was because I didn't want to separate html code for blade and vue. Another reason was that I'd lose a lot of blade functions and need to pass them by parameter instead, that's a lot of props. 


I just decided to pass blade parameters to the component then do everything in the vue component. Good find though.

Comment: You might want to have a look at alpine.js, if you haven't yet. I think it alpine is usually a more appropriate choice for use with laravel and blade.

Comment: furthermore, the alpine.js developer (Caleb Porzio) is also behind the [livewire](https://laravel-livewire.com/) project